# React native paypal wrapper crash on pressing back button

Tags: react-native

```js
paypal(price,bookingId){

    PayPal.initialize(PayPal.SANDBOX, "ARFiHtTEV2P17X4Hdei6M4vqoLx_UVGAvELcTpNprLC4hNklLmNq7cl_z5OqhRGoBzzVRmS9sG-RfhXx");
    PayPal.pay({
            price: price.toString(),
            currency: 'USD',
            description: 'Payment for fuel delivery app',
          })
          .then(confirm => { 
            var pid = confirm.response.id
            this.paypalpaymentapi(price,bookingId,pid)
          })
          .catch(error => Alert.alert(error))
}
```

Above code is for paypal payment in react native.Now the problem in above code is that when `PayPal.initialize` is called and after that when I press back button from initialized paypal then my app crashes and it gives me error that

> class `castexception` can't cast from `readablenativemap` to `String`.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: You can debug this in your Android code and see what `readablenativemap` they are trying to convert to string. from there you can fix the configurations

Comment: it tells cant convert title from readablenativemap to string

Comment: These kind of error usually comes when we pass wrong data, function arguments to native code. You can start the android app in debug mode and enable pause on exception and see which react function call that we are making is causing this error. there you can see the arguments.

Comment: how can i start the app in debug mode?

Comment: Near the run button there is a bug shaped button in android studio. it will start in debug mode. and below debug panel -> left side icons you can see pause on exception